# Can I force all instances of an Angular component to have an attribute?

Tags: angular

If i have a custom component `<my-component></my-component>` can I make it so that it always has a custom attribute? For example, `<my-component data-custom-attr></my-component>`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using an `@Input` and in the `ngOnInit` trigger an error if the value is `null`

```
Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    template: '<div></div>'
})
export class MyComponent {
    @Input() data-custom-attr:number; // Make this a required attribute. Throw an exception if it doesnt exist
    @Input() data-custom-attr-2:number;

    constructor(){

    }

    ngOnInit() {
      if(null == data-custom-attr) throw new Error("Attribute 'data-custom-attr' is required");
    }
}
```

[src solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35528433/6651984)